# Backing up a Cartridge save file

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-sixth-generation

I have all my pokemon games in cartridge format. I'm wondering if it's possible to backup my save on one of my SD cards using the save data transfer tool on eShop. I know it is at least possible with downloaded games.
My plan is to essentially to farm a certain pokemon and check its IVs in a certain way that's easier than using a team to check, but it requires a save; so I am wondering if it's possible to revert to my backup if I don't like it's IVs.

Comment: Probably it's easier if you have [this](http://www.amazon.com/Action-Replay-Powersaves-Cheat-Device-Nintendo/dp/B00CQ9L1Z6)